# How can I set time and date for notification in second time?

Tags: java, android, push-notification

```
.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

is code to set time in push notification android and the result is like `15.54`. But if I want to set time like this `15:54:02` with seconds time what should I do? Can you help me or provide me example source code?

This is my notification-manager source code.

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx);
    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mCtx.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(ID_SMALL_NOTIFICATION, notification);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
}
```

Comment: That fiddling with `notification.defaults` looks non-sensical to me. I'd vote to remove that to not confuse readers, both here and in actual code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set or not millisecond with .setWhen() by default it get that.

Time format what you want to show like `15:54:02` 24 Hour Format with second. There is no settings for time format `NotificationCompat.Builder` class.

What ever you set the millisecond that convert to time to show in notification like `15:54` without second.

What you can do is use custom Notification view rather then default view.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate = "";
    formattedDate = sdf.format(new Date());

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.logo);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, message);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.time, formattedDate);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.home)
            .setContent(contentView);

    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

Layout..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:gravity="left|center_horizontal|center_vertical"
          android:weightSum="4">

<RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/layout"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="3"
      android:layout_height="64dp"
      android:padding="10dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Testing"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Testing is awecome"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:text="Testing"
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Output like this ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> But if i want to set time like this 15:54:02

You cannot have that with built-in notification layout. If you really need seconds, you need to have custom notification layout. But I strongly discourage that.

Comment: but i need it(the second time) its no problem if place in my message not in my notify. i only need when my notification received in my phone in second time. because my program is send notification for network monitoring. i want to analyze time send from server and then receive in my smartphone. or do you have any suggestion how to count delay my notification?

Answer (score 0):

for that, you need to convert that time "14:54:02" in milliseconds and set that result time in `.setWhen()`

Answer (score -1):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss"); 

String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(dateInMillis)));
```